# How to add Mute/Unmute Button on a Video Background [On Divi - WordPress]

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

How can I place a Mute/Unmute Button on a video background (MP4)?

Website Link: http://bsibasketball.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You So Much!

Comment: Please provide some code that you need help with, most likely something like this would work `document.querySelector('video').volume = 1;//0 mute, 1 max`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with this script:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('mute'),
      video = document.querySelector('video');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (btn.value === 'unmuted') {
    btn.value = 'muted';
    btn.innerHTML = 'Unmute';
    video.muted = true;
  } else {
    btn.value = 'unmuted';
    btn.innerHTML = 'Mute';
    video.muted = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<br>
<button id="mute" value="unmuted">Mute</button>
```

You are free to use it however you want. You could also make the user to click on the video instead of a button.